# Como gestionar StackOverflowError en mi test de JUnit4

Tags: java, junit

estoy haciendo una clase de busqueda recursiva y existe un método que es una búsqueda lineal recursiva sobre una ArrayList genérico. Cuando llamamos a este metodo sus parámetros de entrada es un ArrayList, el elemento a buscar y la posición inicial de búsqueda que es 0 en todos los casos.

Estoy haciendo una clase test de la encapsulación mencionada anteriormente con JUnit4, siendo el ArrayList una lista que guarda valores de tipo Integer. Inicializo el ArrayList con 10^6 elementos siendo cada elemento el mismo que su indice, es decir la posición 0 del ArrayList su elemento es 0 y si es 100 será 100.

**El problema**:
Se que cuando quiero buscar el elemento 10^5 me va a dar un error de StackOverflowError. Quería gestionar esto en mi test de JUnit4 con assertThrows ya que estoy seguro de que en el punto que pruebo da este error.

Y en conclusión el problema que tengo es que no se como poner bien los parámetros de entrada del assertThrows para que vaya bien. Y el mensaje de error que me da es: "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final".

El código que hice en el test es el siguiente:

```
public class BusquedaRecursivaIT {
    
    private BusquedaRecursiva busqueda;
    private ArrayList<Integer> list;
    
    public BusquedaRecursivaIT() {
    }
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        busqueda = new BusquedaRecursiva();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testLineal() {
        int elemento;
        int indice;
        int iteraciones;
        int resultado;

        /*
        Buscando el elemento 10^5 y recogiendo la cantidad de iteraciones de la
        busqueda.
        */
        elemento = (int)Math.pow(10, 5);
        indice = busqueda.lineal(list, elemento, 0);
        iteraciones = busqueda.getContador();
        //El elemento se debe encontrar en el indice 10^5 del ArrayList.
        resultado = (int)Math.pow(10, 5);
        //assertEquals(resultado, indice);
        assertThrows(StackOverflowError.class, ()->busqueda.lineal(list, elemento, 0));
        
    }
}
```

La clase BusquedaRecursiva es el siguiente:

```
public class BusquedaRecursiva<E extends Comparable>{
    
    private int contador;
    private int guess;
    
    /**
     * Metodo constructor que inicializa los atributos.
     */
    public BusquedaRecursiva(){
        contador = 0;
        guess = 0;
    }
    
    /**
     * Metodo de busqueda lineal recursivo. Se calcula las veces que se llama
     * a la función para buscar el elemento.<p>
     * 
     * @param list ArrayList con elementos que utiliza la interface Comparable.
     * @param elemento objetivo a buscar.
     * @param posicion indica a la siguiente llamada en que posición se revisa.
     * @return número de consultas a elementos.
     */
    public int lineal(ArrayList<E> list, E elemento, int posicion) {
        contador++;
        if(list.get(posicion).compareTo(elemento) == 0){
            return posicion;
        } 
        if (posicion >= list.size()) {
            return -1;
        }else return this.lineal(list, elemento,posicion+1);
    }

    /**
     * Ver las veces que ha llamado al metodo.
     * 
     * @return numero de veces llamado al metodo.
     */
    public int getContador(){
        return contador;
    }
    
    /**
     * Es un metodo necesario para contar las interacciones. En cuando se llama
     * una vez a uno de los metodos hay que resetear el contador para que el
     * codigo funcione correctamente.
     */
    public void resetContador(){
        contador = 0;
    }

}
```